# subscript out of range error while trying to copy a button

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that was working when the sheet was named "Sheet1".

I changed the name to "Custom".

I get

> subscript out of range

with this line:

```
Set xButton = Sheets("Custom").OLEObjects(ButtonName)
```

It was working with:

```
Set xButton = Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects(ButtonName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have renamed the worksheets using the `(name)` property which refers to the *code name* of the worksheet.

### E.g:

`Sheets("Custom").OLEObjects(ButtonName)` refers to a worksheet which the *sheet name* property has been changed to "Custom".

`Custom.OLEObjects(ButtonName)` refers to a worksheet which the *code name* property has been changed to "Custom"

You can read more about both properties in the following docs:

1. [Codename Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename)
2. [Name Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.name)

### Other things to consider:

It's generally best to explicitly declare your workbook. If you don't, VBA uses `ActiveWorkbook` by default which means you can get `Subscript out of range` errors if your code is running and you have a different workbook in focus.

You can do this like:

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Custom")` or,

Say you have 2 workbooks, `WorkbookA` and `WorkbookB`:
`WorkbookA.Sheets("Custom")` or `WorkbookB.Sheets("Custom")` etc.